# Error while installing and implementing react native device info

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to integrate `react-native-device-info` into my project and when I install the module and link it an error comes up like this

```js
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (15.0.1) and runtime (16.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
    
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
BUILD FAILED in 6s
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

When I configure the project manually same error comes up. But when I unlink react native device info, the project runs well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this block in your `app/build.gradle` file below `buildTypes{}` block and run the app again

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
           force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
    }
}
```